# SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(GEOMETRY) Value Not Allowed Error

Tags: oracle-spatial

i have an object table  and SRID 2000273

[TableGeometryImg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDNdg.jpg)

i execute the following query to get the wkt string of the geometry in the table

```
SELECT SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(GEOMETRY) FROM myTABLE
```

i get following errors;

```
ORA-24323: value not allowed  
ORA-06512: location "MDSYS.MDPRVT_SRID",line 143  
ORA-06512: location "MDSYS.SDO_UTIL", line 320
```

i insert mdsys.cs_srs table about my table's srid record

```
insert into MDSYS.cs_srs values ('TM 27 3 DERECE',2000273,2000273,'Oracle','PROJCS["TM 27 3 DERECE",GEOGCS["OpenGIS.European_Datum_1950",DATUM["OpenGIS.European_Datum_1950",SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388.000000,297.000000]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.000000],UNIT["Decimal Degree",0.01745329251994330]],PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator"],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.000000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",27.000000],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.000000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Latitude_of_Origin",0],UNIT["Meter",1.000000000000]]',NULL);
```

What is the reason for this error? Where else should I check?

Comment: You should indicate what database version you are using

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0):

Your insert actually fails. The `CS_SRS` table (it is actually a view) has more columns than the ones you provide, and therefore, your insert fails as written:

```
SQL> insert into MDSYS.cs_srs values ('TM 27 3 DERECE',2000273,2000273,'Oracle','PROJCS["TM 27 3 DERECE",GEOGCS["OpenGIS.European_Datum_1950",DATUM["OpenGIS.European_Datum_1950",SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388.000000,297.000000]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.000000],UNIT["Decimal Degree",0.01745329251994330]],PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator"],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.000000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",27.000000],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.000000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Latitude_of_Origin",0],UNIT["Meter",1.000000000000]]',NULL);
insert into MDSYS.cs_srs values ('TM 27 3 DERECE',2000273,2000273,'Oracle','PROJCS["TM 27 3 DERECE",GEOGCS["OpenGIS.European_Datum_1950",DATUM["OpenGIS.European_Datum_1950",SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388.000000,297.000000]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.000000],UNIT["Decimal Degree",0.01745329251994330]],PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator"],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.000000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",27.000000],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.000000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Latitude_of_Origin",0],UNIT["Meter",1.000000000000]]',NULL)
                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Let's correct this by using an explicit column list. This is always safer, because the actual ordering of the columns is actually uncertain ...

Notice this insert is only possible when connected as a privileged user. So, let's connect as SYSTEM and do the update:

```
SQL> connect system/******@localdb
Connected.

SQL> insert into cs_srs (cs_name,srid,auth_srid,auth_name,wktext)
  2  values (
  3    'TM 27 3 DERECE',
  4    2000273,
  5    2000273,
  6    'Oracle',
  'PROJCS["TM 27 3 DERECE",GEOGCS["OpenGIS.European_Datum_1950",DATUM["OpenGIS.European_Datum_1950",SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388.000000,297.000000]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.000000],UNIT["Decimal Degree",0.01745329251994330]],PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator"],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.000000],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",27.000000],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.000000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Latitude_of_Origin",0],UNIT["Meter",1.000000000000]]'
  8  );

1 row created.

SQL> commit;
Commit complete.
```

Now the conversion to WKT will work:

```
SQL> select SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(sdo_geometry(2001,2000273,sdo_point_type(449319,4445908,null),null,null)) from dual;

SDO_UTIL.TO_WKTGEOMETRY(SDO_GEOMETRY(2001,2000273,SDO_POINT_TYPE(449319,4445908
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POINT (449319.0 4445908.0)

1 row selected.
```